# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) in ransack scope

Tags: ruby, ransack

[I was getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9yIH.png)

**Controller**

```
def index
 @q = JobSubmission.ransack(search_params[:q])
 @job_submissions = @q.result(distinct: true)
 @job_submissions = @job_submissions.page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

I created a association between Job and Job Submission

**Job.rb model**

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_submissions
end
```

**JobSubmission.rb model**

```
class JobSubmission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  scope :by_job, ->(id) { includes(:job).where(jobs:{id: id}) }

  def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
    %i(by_job)
  end
end
```

**Search form**

```
.search-panel
  %h4 Search File
  = search_form_for(@q, url:admin_job_submissions_path, method: :get, as: :q)  do |f|
    = f.label :by_job, "Job:"
    = f.collection_select(:by_job, Job.all, :id, :job_title, :include_blank => "None")

    = f.submit 'Search' , class: "button action-button__new-button"
```

**I have 2 Jobs and 4 Job Submissions.**

> Job Collection

```
id: 1, job_title: "Job 1"
id: 2, job_title: "Job 2"
```

> Job Submission Collection

```
id: 1, job_id: 1, file: "Job submission 1"
id: 2, job_id: 2, file: "Job submission 2"
id: 3, job_id: 1, file: "Job submission test to 1"
id: 4, job_id: 2, file: "Job Submission test 2"
```

I tested to run this code in my rails console.

> To search for Job Submission with the job id of 1.

```
irb(main):013:0> JobSubmission.ransack({"by_job" => 1}).result
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):13
        1: from app/models/job_submission.rb:6:in `block in <class:JobSubmission>'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
```

> To search for Job Submission with the job id of 2.

```
irb(main):014:0> JobSubmission.ransack({"by_job" => 2}).result
  SQL (1.0ms)  SELECT  "job_submissions"."id" AS t0_r0, "job_submissions"."job_id" AS t0_r1, "job_submissions"."file" AS t0_r2, "job_submissions"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "job_submissions"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "jobs"."id" AS t1_r0, "jobs"."job_title" AS t1_r1, "jobs"."published" AS t1_r2, "jobs"."summary_html" AS t1_r3, "jobs"."body_en_html" AS t1_r4, "jobs"."body_ph_html" AS t1_r5, "jobs"."created_at" AS t1_r6, "jobs"."updated_at" AS t1_r7 FROM "job_submissions" LEFT OUTER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "job_submissions"."job_id" WHERE "jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<JobSubmission id: 2, job_id: 2, file: "Job submission 2", created_at: "2020-10-01 03:14:08", updated_at: "2020-10-01 03:14:08">, #<JobSubmission id: 4, job_id: 2, file: "Job Submission test 2", created_at: "2020-10-01 03:56:10", updated_at: "2020-10-01 03:56:10">]>
```

I tried also to update my gem ransack to master branch but still didnt fix the issue.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was updated my form to this:

**Search form**

```
.search-panel
  %h4 Search File
  = search_form_for(@q, url:admin_job_submissions_path, method: :get, as: :q)  do |f|
    = f.label :job_id_eq, "Job:"
    = f.collection_select(:job_id_eq, Job.all, :id, :job_title, :include_blank => "None")

    = f.submit 'Search' , class: "button action-button__new-button"
```

**Search Params**

```
def search_params
 params.permit(:utf8, :commit, q: [:job_id_eq])
end
```

And remove the scope in JobSubmission.rb model

```
class JobSubmission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Thank you guys...

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by ransack casting `0` to `false` and `1` to `true`.

For simple association ids @Mike Alibo's answer is the best way to do it.

But in case anyone MUST use a scope to search by an id, you can define

```rb
def self.ransackable_scopes_skip_sanitize_args
  %i[your_scope_name]
end
```

on your model to tell ransack to not cast this scope's arguments.

[Docs](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/v2.4.2/README.md#using-scopesclass-methods)